# When does equation $(A^TA)^n=I$ have solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square real matrix. 
We know that if $A$ is orthogonal matrix then $A^TA=I$. Consequently also in this case $(A^TA)^n=I$.

I would like to know whether  it is possible to have expression of type $B=A^TA$  (I would call it transquare of $A$ - btw it is a little strange that such important expression, it seems, has no own name..)  when $A$ is **not** orthogonal matrix, but for some natural $n$ equality $B^n=I$ is satisfied.

- Is it possible?

Of course $B$ is full rank matrix, but on the other hand - in general - the equation $B^n=I$ can have even infinite number of solutions. Could one of them  have  decomposition $A^TA$ without $A$ being orthogonal?

- Can the possible answer  (probably negative)   be also extended for  the case of $ m \times n$ matrices ?

Comment: Thoughts: For sure, $\det(A)$ has to be equal to $(-1)^n$.

Comment: @Yanko Yes, but it is still very broad condition..

Comment: @Yes, in some case it can have, for example for $2 \times 2 $ matrices, other dimensions I have not analyzed..

Comment: Concerning the name ..... I have found today that matrices of form $A^TA$ are called Gramian matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Examples

Comment: @Widawensen the result extends readily to non-square matrices using the SVD.

Comment: @GabrielRomon You may present this kind of solution, it can be interesting, I'm not expert concerning SVD..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would a actually not be possible. If $B=A^TA$ with $A$ real (it doesn't even need to be square) and if $B^n=1$ for some $n$, then $B=I$.

Indeed, $B$ is symmetric and real, hence diagonalisable; moreover it is semidefinite positive, so all its eigenvalues, which I'll denote $\lambda_i$, are nonnegative. Now the eigenvalues of $B^n$ are exactly the $\lambda_i^n$; so $B^n=I$ implies that $\lambda_i^n=1$ for all $i$, and this also implies that $\lambda_i=1$ for all $i$, hence $B$ would actually be the identity.

Comment: Very clear argumentation. Thank you.